# I can not deal with Otto

Tags: android, otto

Otto I use in the project. everything works but I want to improve. Now I have so
I send messages from different places, such as

```
BusProvider.getInstance().post(new QueueMessage(s));
BusProvider.getInstance().post(queue);
BusProvider.getInstance().post(weatherResponse);
```

but all the methods I describe in `MainActivity`

```
@Subscribe
    public void showOttoQueue(Queue queue) {
        new NotificationStorege().setTicker("New message").setTitle("queue").setMessage("You are in the queue: "+queue.queue).generateNotification(this);
    }
    @Subscribe
    public void showGcmMessage(GcmMessage message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "gcm message: " + message.Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Subscribe
    public void showOttoRemoveQueue(QueueMessage message) {
        if (message.Result.equals("OK")){
            new NotificationStorege().setTicker("New message").setTitle("queue").setMessage("you are out of queue").generateNotification(this);
            Toast.makeText(this, "you are out of queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "error out of queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

whether it is possible to create full of class that will store all of these methods? or should they only be in Activity which launched?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use Otto in every single class you want. Just register instance of that class, like in code below. After that events will come to that object.

```
bus.register(classInstance);
```